# Handle multiple buttons with background change events

Tags: android, android-layout

I have many buttons on my view. Each button can have one of three background image. I have cases where on one button click others change status to first background image. Of course I can make ugly switch, remember last selected button but maybe there is some better solution for this case?

Thanks

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private Button bt1;
private Button bt3;
private Button bt4;
private Button bt5;
private Button bt6;
private Button bt7;
private Button bt8;
private Button bt9;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2);
bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt3);
...

bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bt2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.select_button2));
            bt1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.no_select_button1));
            bt3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.no_select_button3));
            ...
            bt9.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.no_select_button9));

        }
    });

  bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bt1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.select_button1));
            bt2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.no_select_button2));
            bt3.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.no_select_button3));
            ...
            bt9.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.no_select_button9));

        }
    });
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you give a snippet of code that demonstrates what you have so far.  If you show an effort you will get answered.  A question like this is likely to get closed.

Comment: Thanks, question updated

Answer (score 0):

I know its late to answer but somebody may need it.Based on [this](https://gist.github.com/granoeste/3291697) githubt gist, add the following codes to OnClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button button = (Button) v;

    // clear state
    mButton1.setSelected(false);
    mButton1.setPressed(false);
    mButton2.setSelected(false);
    mButton2.setPressed(false);
    mButton3.setSelected(false);
    mButton3.setPressed(false);

    // change state
    button.setSelected(true);
    button.setPressed(false);
   }
```